# Infix to Prefix and Postfix conversion

Tags: c, data-structures, stack, postfix-notation, prefix-notation

I'm writing code to convert Infix expression into Postfix and Prefix at the same time.

My problem is I haven't been able to convert into the prefix expression. In my intoprefix() I tried everything, but still the output will same as to the postfix.

Where if i input this expression

```
A+B
```

The expected output would be

```
Postfix expression is: AB+
Prefix expression is: +AB
```

but my output is

```
Postfix expression is: AB+
Prefix expression is: AB+AB+

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Stack{
char data;
struct Stack *next;
}*top = NULL, *pstart = NULL;

char str[50];

int main(int argc, char **argv){
printf("Enter infix expression: ");
gets(str);

printf("\n\nEquivalent postfix expression is: ");
intopostfix(str);

printf("\n\nEquivalent prefix expression is: ");
intoprefix(str);
printf("\n");
return 0;
}

/* function for insert operation */
void insert(char ch){

    struct Stack *ptr,*newNode;
    newNode = (struct Stack *)malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->data = ch;
    ptr = pstart;

    if(pstart == NULL){
    pstart = newNode;
    }
    else{
    while(ptr->next != NULL)
    ptr = ptr->next;
    ptr->next = newNode;
    }

}

/* function for push operation */
void push(char symbol){

    struct Stack *ptr;

        ptr = (struct Stack *)malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
        ptr->data = symbol;

        if(top == NULL){
            top = ptr;
            ptr->next = NULL;
        }
        else{
            ptr->next = top;
            top = ptr;
    }
}

char pop(){

    struct Stack *ptr1;
    char ch1;

        if(top == NULL){
        printf("Stack underflow\n");
        return 0;
        }
        else{
            ptr1 = top;
            top = top->next;
            ch1 = ptr1->data;
            free(ptr1);
            ptr1 = NULL;
            return ch1;
        }
}

/* function for display display operation */
void displaypost(){

    struct Stack *temp;

        if(pstart == NULL)
            printf("");
        else{           
            temp = pstart;
        while(temp != NULL){
        printf("%c",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}

/*function for precedence */
int precedence(char ch){

        if(ch   ==  '^'){
        return (5);
        }
        else if(ch == '*' || ch == '/'){
        return (4);
        }
        else if(ch == '+' || ch == '-'){
        return (3);
        }
        else{
        return (2);
        }
}
 /*function for converting infix to postfix */
void intopostfix(char str[]){

    int length;
    int index = 0;
    char symbol, temp;
    length = strlen(str);

    while(length > index)
    {
        symbol = str[index];

        switch(symbol){

        case '(':
        push(symbol);
        break;

        case ')':
        temp = pop();

        while(temp != '('){
        insert(temp);
        temp = pop();
        }

        break;

        case '^':
        case '+':
        case '-':
        case '*':
        case '/':

        if(top == NULL){
            push(symbol);
        }
        else{
        while(top != NULL && (precedence(top->data) >= precedence(symbol))){
            temp = pop();
            insert(temp);
            }
            push(symbol);
        }   
            break;
            default:
            insert(symbol);
         }
         index = index + 1;
    }
        while(top != NULL){
        temp = pop();
        insert(temp);
    }

        displaypost();
        return;
}
/*function to convert infix to prefix */
void intoprefix(char str[]){

    int length;
    int index = 0;
    char symbol, temp;
    length = strlen(str);

    while(length > index)
    {
        symbol = str[index];

        switch(symbol){

        case ')':
        temp = pop();
        break;

        case '(':
        push(symbol);


        while(temp != ')'){
        insert(temp);
        temp = pop();
        }

        break;

        case '+':
        case '-':
        case '*':
        case '/':
        case '^':

        if(top == NULL){
            push(symbol);
        }
        else{
        while(top != NULL && (precedence(top->data) <= precedence(symbol))){
            temp = pop();
            insert(temp);
            }
            push(symbol);
        }   
            break;
            default:
            insert(symbol);
         }
         index = index + 1;
    }
        while(top != NULL){
        temp = pop();
        insert(temp);
    }

        displaypost();
        return;
}
```

The program converts infix to postfix and prefix using linked lists (stacks)

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't forget how to create a [mcve], with emphasis on the *minimal* part. Lastly, if you haven't done it yet, then now is probably a very good time to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code.

Comment: A few other hints in making your code better: Don't use global variables. If a variable is needed in multiple functions, pass it as an argument. Also in C you [don't need to (and really shouldn't) cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). And try to use consistent indentation, it will make the code much easier to read, understand and debug.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my observations and amendments:

1. Received a warning about `gets`. Have used `fgets` instead.`gets` is
   dangerous as it may cause a buffer overflow.
2. Freed the storages allocated in the `insert` function.The presence of
   these locations were causing the duplication of results,when
   `intoprefix` was called.
3. Since you already have an `intopostfix` function, I utilized the same
   to convert `infix` to `prefix` using the following algorithm. Please
   [refer](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-infix-prefix-notation/).

   Step 1:Reverse the infix expression. Note while reversing each ‘(‘ will
   become ‘)’ and each ‘)’ becomes ‘(‘.

   Step 2:Obtain the postfix expression of the modified expression.

   Step 3:Reverse the postfix expression.
4. Made `main` the owner of the arrays that store the input and results, thus avoiding the use of "global variables" and requiring me to pass these variables explicitly.
5. Removed the `displaypost` function from within `intopostfix` and am
   calling it from `main`.

   ```
   void insert(char ch);//no changes made
   void push(char symbol); //no changes made
   char pop(); //no changes made
   void displaypost(char * s);
   int precedence(char ch); //no changes made
   void intopostfix(char str[]); //removed the call to displaypost

   int main(int argc, char **argv){
     char str[50];
     char prefix_str[50];//store postfix str
     char postfix_str[50];//store prefix str

     printf("Enter infix expression: ");
     fgets(str,50,stdin);
     str[strlen(str)-1] = '\0';//overwrite newline char with NULL

     //reverse the original string and store in prefix_str
     int i,j;

     for(i = strlen(str)-1,j = 0;i >= 0;i--,j++){
       if(str[i] == '(')
         prefix_str[j] = ')';
       else if(str[i] == ')')
         prefix_str[j] = '(';
       else
         prefix_str[j] = str[i];
     }
     prefix_str[j] = '\0';

     //Print Post Fix
     printf("\n\nEquivalent postfix expression is: ");
     intopostfix(str);
     displaypost(postfix_str);
     printf("%s",postfix_str);

     //Print Prefix
     intopostfix(prefix_str);
     displaypost(prefix_str);
     //reverse prefix_str
     int temp;
     for(i = 0,j = strlen(prefix_str)-1;i < j;i++,j--){
       temp = prefix_str[i];
       prefix_str[i] = prefix_str[j];
       prefix_str[j] = temp;
     }
     printf("\n\nEquivalent prefix expression is: ");
     printf("%s\n",prefix_str);
     printf("\n");
     return 0;
   }

   //changes in displaypost
   void displaypost(char * s){
     struct Stack *temp,*p;
     if(pstart == NULL)
       printf("");
     else{           
       temp = pstart;
       int i = 0;
       while(temp != NULL){
       p = temp;
       s[i] = temp->data;//store character in array
       temp = temp->next;
       free(p);//free storage
       i++;
       }
       s[i] = '\0';
     }
     pstart = NULL;
   }
   ```